# How to retrieve PersonAccount field picklist field value set with sfdx?

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, person-accounts, health-cloud

We have our org configured with person accounts, and have the Health Cloud managed package installed.

The Health Cloud managed package adds a field `HealthCloudGA__Gender__c` to the PersonAccount object.

On the Account/Contact object, we have added to the values in the picklist for this field. As in we have gone to Object Manager > Contact > Fields and Relationships > Gender > Values > added a value.

We have **then** made a custom recordtype for a person account, and version controlled it. In that record type, we reference one of the custom values we added to the picklist:

`force-app/main/default/objects/PersonAccount/recordTypes/Member.recordType-meta.xml`:

```
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>HealthCloudGA__Gender__pc</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>Female</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Male</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>ND</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    ...
```

When we try to deploy this metadata to a new scratch org, we get:

```
PersonAccount.OurCustomRecordType
Picklist value: ND in picklist: HealthCloudGA__Gender__pc not found
```

Here's where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to retrieve these custom picklist values via sfdx. I've tried all sorts of combinations of things like:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet:AccountGender'
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet:ContactGender'
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'ValueSet:ContactGender'
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet:PersonAccountGender'
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m 'StandardValueSet:PersonAccountMemberGender'
```

And many more combinations. **How can I use sfdx to retrieve the values in this picklist, so that we may deploy our custom record types?**

Comment: Could be because it's managed, but does this work? sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Account.HealthCloudGA__Gender__pc or Contact.HealthCloudGA__Gender__c

Comment: Or just -m CustomObject:Contact / Account

Comment: Also, you'll have to have the package installed in the scratch org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment on the original question pointed me in the right direction. Retrieving the **field**, not the value set, allowed for deploying this to a sandbox. I ran:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Contact.HealthCloudGA__Gender__c
```

(Person account fields ending in `__pc` must be retrieved from the contact as `__c`)